# Enable CORS in Backpack framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, bookshelf.js, helmet.js

Link for official Documentation : [Backpack](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack)

As Backpack is a minimalistic build system for Node.js projects, I am using Backpack Build as my Back-end App("**Auth-api**" - locally running on my system) and sending request from another front-end application("**Management-App**"- Angular 5 application) to the routes defined in **Auth-Api** but instead of getting response, I am getting this **error** in my browser console:

> Request header field accept-version is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Also, I am using the [Bookshelf_ORM](http://bookshelfjs.org/) and [Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) also. I am not sure, if **Helmet** is causing this issue or not. Moreover, I am not able to find any other proper documentation for Backpack. So, any suggestion or valid link for proper documentation would also be helpful which eventually helps to solve the issue.

Comment: please explain what did you do and what you want to achieve when getting this error.

Comment: We don't know which servers are involved, or which server you are making the request to that is causing the browser to give that error.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it @Saeed

Comment: I have updated the question, please check it @Quentin

Comment: I'm pretty sure Bookshelf is in no way related with this issue. Clearly the problem seems to be that the `accept-version` header is not allowed by your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` setup.